# Use Custom Image for PrimeReact Data Tree Icon

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I'm using the Data Tree component from PrimeReact, docs linked below. The tree component takes in an object with fields defined as such

```
const data = [
    {
        "key": "0",
        "label": "Documents",
        "data": "Documents Folder",
        "icon": "pi pi-fw pi-inbox",
        "children": [{
            "key": "0-0",
            "label": "Work",
            "data": "Work Folder",
            "icon": "pi pi-fw pi-cog",
            "children": [{ "key": "0-0-0", "label": "Expenses.doc", "icon": "pi pi-fw pi-file", "data": "Expenses Document" }, { "key": "0-0-1", "label": "Resume.doc", "icon": "pi pi-fw pi-file", "data": "Resume Document" }]
        },
        {
            "key": "0-1",
            "label": "Home",
            "data": "Home Folder",
            "icon": "pi pi-fw pi-home",
            "children": [{ "key": "0-1-0", "label": "Invoices.txt", "icon": "pi pi-fw pi-file", "data": "Invoices for this month" }]
        }]
    }
]
```

called as such

```
<Tree value={data} />
```

The icon attribute determines the symbol rendered next to the label tag. I want to use my own .png in place of the icons available. I would initially try to add an img tag but this does not seem to work. If anymore information is needed please let me know.

https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/tree

Answer (score -1):

try using css. In your `css` file:

```
youricon{
  background-image: url('local-url');
}
```

So it goes like this:

```
const data = [
    {
        "key": "0",
        "label": "Documents",
        "data": "Documents Folder",
        "icon": "youricon",
        "children": [{
            "key": "0-0",
            "label": "Work",
            "data": "Work Folder",
            "icon": "youricon",
            "children": [{ "key": "0-0-0", "label": "Expenses.doc", "icon": "pi pi-fw pi-file", "data": "Expenses Document" }, { "key": "0-0-1", "label": "Resume.doc", "icon": "pi pi-fw pi-file", "data": "Resume Document" }]
        },
        {
            "key": "0-1",
            "label": "Home",
            "data": "Home Folder",
            "icon": "youricon",
            "children": [{ "key": "0-1-0", "label": "Invoices.txt", "icon": "pi pi-fw pi-file", "data": "Invoices for this month" }]
        }]
    }
]
```

On a related note, try using icons which are easily available like `FontAwesome`, `FeatherIcons`, `Octicons`. If you are using primereact, It's updated version has its own icons `primeicons`.

You need to install it first using: `npm install primeicons --save` .

You can get more details here: `https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/icons`